# how to send data to a Lotus Notes Eclipse Plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, lotus-notes, communication

I would like to send a message to an Eclipse plugin - that I'm developing - which is installed inside IBM Lotus Notes, from a third party app(an Internet Explorer extension).

If I access notes.exe with some argument, that won't be forwarded to my plugin. I am not really aware of my options here.

Thanks

Comment: please consider leaving a comment if there is anything I can rephrase or add, thank you

Comment: Care to share the name of the plugin and third party app? I dont see how you can do it without the plugin or app providing an interface, Note : I am not the downvoter

Comment: Added, thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this unless the plugin itself supports some method of communication.

You could try calling `Platform.getApplicationArgs()` which in an ordinary Eclipse RCP will give you the program arguments - I don't know if this works for Lotus Notes. Eclipse normally just ignores arguments it does not understand so your plugin can support additional arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, is there maybe some method that I could research? What can my plugin listen to?

Comment: I have added a way to get at the program arguments that may work for you.

Comment: thank you Greg! It seems like notes.exe does not forward the arguments though. Maybe there is a way for the plugin to listen to incoming data? One of my colleagues suggested that I just start a server inside the plugin and deploy an app on that server that sends data to the plugin...but that sounds like overkill

Comment: There is no other standard way in Eclipse. Lotus Notes is a strange combination of Eclipse RCP and C code, it might have something else but I don't have any up to date knowledge of Notes. Otherwise a server or checking for a particular file might work.